# Create phone call with Mockaroo for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm following this [guide](https://neo4j.com/blog/use-phone-calls-identify-criminals/) to create a dataset with a call log.
But i don't understand the datatype used for the Date fields and the condition for Start_Date, End_Date and Duration to have coerent values (for example date_start = 10/10/10:1050 date_end=10/10/10:10.55 DURATION = 5)

Answer (score 1):

In [that guide](https://neo4j.com/blog/use-phone-calls-identify-criminals/), `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` are expressed in [UNIX epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC time zone).

*By the way, you will get much better support for neo4j questions at stackoverflow.com.*